# Convert exponential number to discrete number

Tags: pandas, type-conversion

I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
  Source    Code    DateTime    Actual
0    4      78     2016-09-18   6.618372e+01
1    4      124    2016-09-18   2.470248e+06
2    4      37     2016-09-16   1.260494e+01
3    4      5      2016-09-16   1.769238e+08
4    4      19     2016-09-16   1.000000e+00
```

I am trying to plot the Actual value using matplotlib. But since this has exponential values in it, I am getting an error. Just wondering is there a way to convert this exponential number to a discrete number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post an output of `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: Source        int64,
Code          int64,
DateTime     object,
Actual      float64

Comment: It works just fine for me: `df.Actual.plot(figsize=(12,8))`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `float` values when plotting. They are not required to be integers. Your question does not make sense. What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [91]: df.Actual.plot(figsize=(12,8))
Out[91]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x8f72390>

In [92]: df
Out[92]:
   Source  Code    DateTime        Actual
0       4    78  2016-09-18  6.618372e+01
1       4   124  2016-09-18  2.470248e+06
2       4    37  2016-09-16  1.260494e+01
3       4     5  2016-09-16  1.769238e+08
4       4    19  2016-09-16  1.000000e+00

In [93]: df.dtypes
Out[93]:
Source        int64
Code          int64
DateTime     object
Actual      float64
dtype: object
```

[image]

Comment: I used Google Charts, i.e. for each day, to print the Actual. 

I used -- %%chart line --fields Source,Code,DateTime,Actual --data df1

Comment: @user3447653, i didn't get it. Can you explain what do you want to plot (x-axis, y-axis)?